# Do Jedi masters/knights take responsibility for their turned padawans?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, jedi-training

After reading [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/148660/75000) about how Master Kreia was exiled after her padawan turned against the Jedi, I started wondering if it was common for Jedi masters to be reprimanded when one of their padawan turned to the Dark Side. The only other cases I can think of are Obi-Wan's padawan, Anakin, and Luke's, Ben. But both Obi and Luke could be considered "lucky" since the entire Jedi order fell immediately following the birth of Darth Vader, and there *was no order* when Kylo Ren came to be, so they might have gotten their failures "forgiven" considering the circumstances.

So was Kreia a special case since her teachings were already disliked by the Council, **or do all Jedi suffer consequences if their padawan falls from the Light? If so, what are they?**

Examples of consequences include:

- Suspension
- Exile
- Investigation
- Re-training
- Demotion
- Fine/community service
- Seppuku (or something similar)

Examples of what **would not** be considered a punishment:

- Any kind of self-infliction of the above
- Feeling bad
- Feeling guilty

I guess this might be two questions if you count asking about Kreia, but the important one is in the title.

Legends answers are fine.

Comment: In living memory (and this includes Yoda, who's 900 years old) there are practically no Jedi who turned to the dark side of the Force.

Comment: @Valorum - Well, the example in the question was from Old Republic times, so that’s long before Yoda. Besides, weren’t there a bunch of dark Jedi (*not* Sith) in Legends?

Comment: @Adamant - fair enough. In that case the question is unanswerable since our knowledge of the early days of the Jedi order is very limited.

Comment: Yoda trained Dooku (who obviously turned to the Sith and became Darth Tyranus) yet Yoda faced no apparent consequences.

Comment: When Exar Kun turned to the dark side, Vodo Siosk Bass wasn't booted from the council.

Comment: @Null Dooku didn't turn right away.  He actually left the order.  Years later he fell to the dark side.

Comment: This can't be answered definitively as written. Too broad. No definition of what "take responsibility" means and doesn't. What is considered a "consequence"? Does it have to be an official sanction or reprimand, or is personal guilt enough to satisfy? Etc.

Comment: The example I gave was an **official** consequence from the council. I don't think "feeling guilty" ever qualifies as "taking responsibility". I'm sure Luke felt super guilty when Ben killed every other student (especially since he was Luke's BBF's son), but that was not considered to be punishment in the question.

Comment: And according to @Valorum, this question was already unanswerable due to the lack of knowledge on the subject, so no need to downvote

Answer (score 5):

If we strictly stick to **canon**:

1) When **Dooku** turned to the dark side, none of the punishments you mentioned were given to **Yoda**, his master.

2) **Quinlan Vos** briefly turned to the dark side. There was no mention in the Dark Disciple novel of any action being taken against his master, **Tholme**.

These are the two examples that can be used to simply say "no" to your question.

However, the latest example can make us wonder about the New Jedi Order. When **Kylo Ren** turns to the dark side, **Luke**, the founder of the order, goes into self imposed exile. Although this can be purely out of guilt, it can also possibly be that the master does go into exile if your *current* padawan turns to the dark side (the previous two examples dealt with *former* masters).

If we go into **Legends**, then I don't think there was any such case where the master would suffer consequences, but then again I refer to *former masters*. (**Revan** and **Malek** were both full fledged Knights during the war on Mandalore.) We also have the example of **Exar Kun** from legends, but I haven't read about him much.

Comment: Thanks for the distinction between *former* and *current* masters